# How many arrangements of the digits $0,1,....,9$ are there that do not end with an $8$ and do not begin with a $3$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

Using inclusion exclusion principles,

> How many arrangements of the digits $0,1,....,9$ are there that do not end with an $8$ and do not begin with a $3$?

Here are my workings, are they correct? or where did I go wrong? I am not sure if I used to the intersection and union of $A$ and $B$ correctly

let,

$n(A)=$ number of arrangements ending with $8=9!$
$n(B)=$ number of arrangements beginning with $3=9!$
$n(E)=$ total number of arrangements $=10!$
$n(A\bigcap B)= 8!$

We require: $n(E)-n(A\bigcup B)$
but $n(A\bigcup B)= n(A) + n(B) - n(A\bigcap B)$
Since $A$ and $B$ are not mutually exclusive, so
$n(E) - (n(A)+n(B)-(n(A\bigcap B)) = 10!-(9!+9!-8!)$

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no. beginning with 0 is valid,

no. of arrangements=$n(\text{total possibilities})-n(\text{no.s with }3\text{ at start and end with  }8)$

$n=10!-8!$

Comment: this is a different solution to what I had

Comment: Subtracted should be the number of arrangements that start with $3$ **or** end with $8$.

Comment: @drhab In the question, he has mentioned "and". And my answer suits his condition. There's ambiguity in what he's asking for.

Comment: I have edited to make it possible to withdraw my downvote.

Comment: @drhab So, my answer is correct as per the specified conditions??!!

Answer (score 0):

There are $10!$ permutations at all.  Now $1\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1$ start with a three and end with an eight.  Now subtract.

Comment: You subtracted the number of arrangement that end with an $8$ and begin with a $3$.  However, we have to ensure that the sequences neither end with an $8$ nor begin with a $3$.

Comment: Yes, that’s what the OP asked for, didn’t he?  He asked for 'and’.